# Easily search for bugs in team server (TFS) using Google type search

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have had this issue at multiple companies I have been with. When you start to have many testers on a team and many bugs in TFS and you simply want to see if someone else already found the bug you just found. In team server I don't see an easy global text search option to find bugs using similar keywords. You have to make a query instead of just doing a Google search everything type search. Very annoying. Is there any way that you can do this I am not aware of? I am using TFS 2012.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3f31bfff-5ecb-4e05-8356-04815851b8e7) extension yet?

Comment: No but it pointed me in the link to answer my question

Comment: Awesome... glad I could  _sort of_ help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you can search for bugs in TFS 2012

[image: This is where you can search for bugs in TFS 2012]